# Can i listen for onCreate to finish

Tags: android

I have a method that takes a while to execute, and i need it at the start of my activity.  If i put it in the onCreate method it will slow down the actual loading of the activity.  Is there a way to listen for onCreate to be done, and then call the method so the user does not have a blank screen while the laborsome method is running.

Comment: `OnStart() is calling after onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method you are calling takes a while to execute then no matter where in the activity lifecycle you execute it, it will cause a disruption to the user experience (a "frozen" screen). Maybe you could instead disable the UI, perhaps put up a loading spinner and do the work in an [`AsyncTask`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). You can hide the spinner and re-enable the rest of the UI after the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

try impementing Async which has `doInBacground` method which can help you get what you want. here is a nice tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html